# How to combine modules reports in one project in Sonar

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I setup project for sending reports to SonarQube according to this example https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/android/android-sonarqube-scanner.

My project have several modules:

- module1
- module2

As result there are 2 projects in SonarQube (for each module).

Is it possible to combine reports data in one SonarQube Project from these 2 modules?

Example of module1 setup:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "Module1"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "module1"
        property "sonar.java.binaries", "./build/intermediates/classes/staging/debug"
        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "./build/test-results/testDebugUnitTest"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", "./build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"
        property "sonar.android.lint.report", "./build/reports/lint-results.xml"
        def sonarLibraries = configurations.compile.join(",")
        property 'sonar.java.libraries', sonarLibraries
        property "sonar.host.url", "localhost"
        property "sonar.login", "token"
        property "sonar.scm.provider", "git"
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.sources", "./src/main"
        property "sonar.tests", "./src/test/java"
        property "sonar.exclusions", "build/**,**/*.png,**/*.jpg,**/*.gif"
        property "sonar.import_unknown_files", true
        property "sonar.dynamicAnalysis", "reuseReports"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I find out how to do it.

I removed all sonar setting and plugins from module's gradle files and put to the root `build.gradle`.

Pay attention that module's name starts with `:`. Without it sonar doesn't apply my settigns to the module.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
//...
}

apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "MultiModuleProject"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "mmp"
        property "sonar.modules", ":module1,:module2"

        property ":module1.sonar.java.binaries", "..."
        property ":module1.sonar.junit.reportsPath", "..."
        property ":module1.sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", "..."
        property ":module1.sonar.android.lint.report", "..."
        property ":module1.sonar.sources", "./src/main"
        property ":module1.sonar.tests", "./src/test/java"

        property ":module2.sonar.java.binaries", "..."
        property ":module2.sonar.junit.reportsPath", "..."
        property ":module2.sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", "..."
        property ":module2.sonar.android.lint.report", "..."
        property ":module2.sonar.sources", "./src/main"
        property ":module2.sonar.tests", "./src/test/java"
        //----
        property "sonar.host.url", "host"
        property "sonar.login", "..."
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
    }
}
```

Comment: How we exclude some files and packages with in thease modules?

Comment: didn't tried it, but may be `property ":module1.sonar.exclusions", "build/**,**/*.png,**/*.jpg,**/*.gif"`